# Traefik is redirecting some sites instead of acting like reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to configure traefik to be used as a reverse-proxy. So that instead of `my-site.com` users would see `my-traefik-domain.com` in url, but would access `my-site.com`
My configuration works nicely for several sites like `google.com` but doesn't work with specific site I need `https://sip1.mycompany.nl:1443/`  I assume it's related to port, but I have made few tries with `http://portquiz.net:8/` an it worked nicely.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, here is my configuration files.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - proxy2

    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.file=true"
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/rules.yml"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./etc/traefik/rules.yml:/etc/traefik/rules.yml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`docker-proxy.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=myapp-website@file"
networks:
  proxy2:
    external: true
```

rules.yml

```
http:
  services:
    myapp-website:
      loadBalancer:
        passHostHeader: false
        servers:
        - url: "https://sip1.mycompany.nl:1443/login/admin"
        # this works
        # - url: "http://portquiz.net:8/"
        # So as this
        # - url: "https://google.com"
```

I have tried configuring traefik by examples from documentation, and it works for all cases, except the one I need.

I expect configuration to work for url with port 1443.